# Loop function only execute once

Tags: excel, loops, offset, vba

The code below works fine without error, it goes inside a macro which loops through files in a folder. Automating data entry. However my loop function only execute once.

```
DoEvents


Worksheets("Data").Activate
'Variable Declarations
Dim IEDepth As Double, DDiv As Double, NoRow As Integer, Irow As Integer, LR As Range, LR2 As Range
Dim IName As String, IDate As Date, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
IEDepth = Worksheets("Data").Range("D9")    

DDiv = 0.5
NoRow = IEDepth / DDiv

'Loop only perform once
Do Until Irow = NoRow
'LR.Offset(1, 0).Value = DDiv
Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = DDiv
Range("G1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = DDiv
Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = IName
Range("K1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = IDate
DDiv = DDiv + 0.5
Irow = Irow + 1
Loop

'Save and Close Workbook
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents
```

Appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jsheeran - I believe it creates multiple new rows with a progressive DDiv value.

Comment: What's currently in `Worksheets("Data").Range("D9")`?

Comment: @jsheeran because IEDepth varies from one file to another. Thus entries varies from file to file. Number of files x every date of the month = not an easy task

Comment: @jeeped a decimal value indicating depth of object

Comment: Why are you showing us code that you say works without error? The code which does the looping that you allude to but haven't shown is likely the source of the problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman I thought it would help to explain my function better, knowing how the code flows

Comment: @JohnColeman I thought it would help to explain my function better, knowing how the code flows

Comment: @Tyler doubtless this code is relevant if it will be called in a loop, but your question reads like "Here is some code that works. I have some other code that doesn't work. How should I fix my other code?"

Comment: @JohnColeman alright. I taken out the codes, that's irrelevant to the loop.
the loop shown above now is what's require to execute for every workbook the outer loops open. However, is only operating once now, Whereas the other functions you saw previously are able to carry on with each workbook it opens.

Comment: The code as shown executes loop `IEDepth*2` times, so there is something else involved.

Answer (score 1):

With the information you have provided here is what we can do.

Your loop depends on Irow = Norow to stop executing. You need to know each variable value each loop, to trace when this case is going to be true (which seems to be true for the 2nd loop).

*First loop*

```
Irow = 0
IEDepth = D9
DDiv = 0.5
NoRow = D9 / 0.5
```

So it is clear that Irow <> Norow on the first loop, but it the second loop Irow = NoRow

*Second loop*

```
Irow = 1
IEDepth = D9
DDiv = 1
NoRow = D9 / 0.5
```

Said that, In order for Irow = NoRow, NoRow value is 1, or D9 value is 0.5.

I suggest to insert the following code inside each loop (after the Do command and other one before the Loop command), so you can monitor each variables value

```
MsgBox(Irow & vbCrLf & IEDepth & vbCrLf & DDiv & vbCrLf & NoRow)
```

Unfortunatelly, with no further information, we can't help you anymore.

Comment: I found out the problem with MsgBox. My variable `IEDepth`, `Irow`, `DDiv` & `NoRow` needs to reset. How do i do that? Because it wouldn't clear the memory until `end sub` is reached, which is in the outer loop

Comment: Actually I got it already. Thanks for the help. I just had to set it all to 0 after the loop